# Webclient.UploadString() sends an empty string

Tags: c#, post, webclient

Here's some code:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.BaseAddress = "http://localhost/";
client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
client.Proxy = null;
// The server gets the data
var responseStr = client.UploadString(url, data); 
...
// The server gets an empty post data
responseStr = client.UploadString(url, data);
```

Is Webclient supposed to be an disposable thing?

Comment: What's the contents of the `data` variable?

Comment: A pair of keys: json=foo&checksum=sha1(foo). I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually it matters because if you don't encode it properly the server won't be able to decode it.

Comment: I tested UploadString two times with both the same data and the url. When I create a new WebClient every time, it's all ok.

Answer (score 0):

hmm may be u cant try this :

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.BaseAddress = "http://localhost/something.php";
```